# How to fix git messup after 'git svn rebase'?

Tags: git, git-svn

I had a clean working git(-svn) repository with a lot of new commits. Let's label this the 'original' state.

Then I made a `git svn rebase` which gave a lot of conflicts and the choices:

```
When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
```

Also, all the commits I have made are gone (i.e. `git log`) does not show them anymore.

How can I get to the above described 'original' state? I.e. the state I have been in BEFORE I typed the command `git svn rebase`? I do not quite understand what the mentioned choices really mean...

Comment: `git rebase --abort`?

Comment: Just git rebase, or git svn rebase?

Comment: `git rebase --abort`, this abort the rebase.

Answer (score 1):

Do as the help text advices:

```
git rebase --abort
```

This will return you to the state before the rebase began.